# Где в ошибка в коде PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь сделать форму изменение записей БД используя ajax, сам скрипт работает нормально, а PHP код не работает выдает ошибку запроса постоянно, вот код:

```
<?php
$article_title = $_POST['article_title'];
$article_titleid = $_POST['article_titleid'];
$connect = new mysqli("host", "user", "pasword", "bdname");

if($connect->query("update tovar set article_title = '$article_title' where id = '$article_titleid'"))
  echo "OK";
else
  echo "ОШИБКА В ЗАПРОСЕ!";
?>
```

Comment: Вы не проверяете что подключение прошло успешно. Вы не пытаетесь получить реально уходящий в базу запрос и выполнить его "руками" в консоли БД.

Comment: Распечатайте текст запроса после подстановки переменных. ошибка скорее всего и найдется. по тому что вы тут пртивели невозможно сказать что не так. А вообще подставлять переменные в кавычках непосредственно в запрос нельзя. Используйте связывание параметров. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: А что у вас в логе ошибок?

Comment: были ошибки с ключами, исправил, теперь выдает "OK" но данные в базу не вносит

Comment: Если данные не вносит, может id несуществующий передается вот оно и не находит строчку которую модифицировать